# Using QgsNetworkContentFetcher to POST data

Tags: pyqgis, http-post

When programming a QGis plugin, I would like to POST a .json-file to a remote server; preferably using `QgsNetworkContentFetcher` to do this on the background while waiting for a response.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to configure this as a POST request.

My current code is something like:

```
def fetch_non_blocking(url, callback, onerror, postData=None):
    fetcher = QgsNetworkContentFetcher()
    def onFinished():
        callback(fetcher.contentAsString())
    
    fetcher.finished.connect(onFinished)
    request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url))
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent","anyways.eu QGIS-plugin")
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    fetcher.fetchContent(request)
```

which works fine for  GET-request, but not a POST

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it will always use GET:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/864fee0172ddd80438633e714591a0fadcf96de0/src/core/network/qgsnetworkcontentfetcher.cpp#L66 in the fetchContent method reads:

```
... QgsNetworkAccessManager::instance()->get( request );
```

and there is no apparent code path that could use a different HTTP method.